# Get attributes of a parent tag in XML

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I've got this little piece of XML:

```
<tile x="764" y="491" z="7">
    <item id="1988"/>
    <inside>
        <item id="3972"/>
    </inside>
</tile>
<tile x="764" y="492" z="7">
    <item id="2343"/>
</tile>
<tile x="764" y="491" z="7">
    <item id="2000"/>
    <inside>
        <item id="3972" special_description="whatever"/>
    </inside>
</tile>
<tile x="765" y="491" z="7">
    <item id="2114"/>
</tile>
<tile x="764" y="491" z="7">
    <item id="1988"/>
</tile>
```

I would like to get the tile attribute details based on a search for a specific attribute in the item tag. For example, if I were to look for 3972, I would get a result of something like this:

```
x="764" y="491" z="7" : id="3972"
x="764" y="491" z="7" : id="3972" special_description="whatever"
```

Obviously how exactly are the results worded is not really important as long as I only have the details I'm looking for, which is attributes of the [[tile]] tag if there is an [[item]] with [[id="3972"]] within it and display the attributes of that [[item]] as well and omit other tiles.

I tried my luck with XMLStarlet but I had no luck so far, any clues?

Comment: can You show us the XMLStarlet attempts?

Comment: I was mostly playing with the basic functions can't tell right now, left my machine at work.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can give a try to this one:

```
$ term="2114";awk -v term=$term '{a[NR]=$0; if ($0 ~ term) \ 
{i=NR;while (a[i] !~ "<tile x=.+ y=.+ z=.+") i--; \
print gensub(/(<tile) (.+)(>)/,"\\2","g",a[i]),":", \
gensub(/([ ]*)(<item )(.+)(\/>)/,"\\3","g",$0)}} ' file5
```

Offcourse the use of a proper parser for that kind of data should be your first choice. In the meanwhile, it seems that above works ok (tested with all of your advised data).